# Removed menu item, how to make menu bar expand to fill space?

Tags: html, css

I have removed a menu item from a navigation bar but now the bar does not expand to fill the screen width so it is shorter than the actual page content now. How do I make it do this? I tried putting in width:100% but that didn't make any difference.

This is the code I have:

```
   <ul id="PrimaryNav" class="clearfix">
        <li><a href="index.php" title="Home Page">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php" title="About">About&#47;FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="priceguide.php" title="Prices Guide">Price Guide</a></li>
        <li><a href="packages.php" title="Packages">Packages</a></li>
    <!--    <li><a href="laser-lipo.php" title="Laser Lipo">Laser Lipo</a></li> -->
        <li><a href="acne.php" title="Skincare">Skincare</a></li>
        <li><a href="pcos.php" title="PCOS">PCOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="testimonials.php" title="Testimonials" class="last">Testimonials</a></li>
    </ul>

    ul#PrimaryNav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    clear: left;
    display: block;
}    
        ul#PrimaryNav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 12.5%;
    float: left;
    background: transparent url('../img/primarynavbg.jpg') bottom left repeat-x;
}
    ul#PrimaryNav li a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-right: solid 1px #f1f1f1;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #dcdcdc;
}
```

Comment: Change the % width of the `li` to 100 / number of list items.

Comment: ul#PrimaryNav li width : 14.28%

Comment: I tried this also and it didn't make any difference. I'm just editing the .css file in cpanel, do I have to do anything to force the changes to take effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `display: block` to `ul` element, I used `display: table; width: 100%;` and for `li` element, I used `display: table-cell` instead of `display: inline-block;`.

**CSS**

```
ul#PrimaryNav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    clear: left;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
ul#PrimaryNav li {
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: transparent url('../img/primarynavbg.jpg') bottom left repeat-x;
}
ul#PrimaryNav li a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-right: solid 1px #f1f1f1;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #dcdcdc;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8v5t11sg/)**

Comment: Thank you - I just tried this but nothing is changing. Do I have to do something to force the .css changes to take effect? I am refreshing the browser too so it's not a browser caching issue.

Comment: @Sarah did you clear the browser cache? _also check whether you are changing the correct file path_

Comment: Hi, yeah I did clear it (also tried a different browser) and I'm sure I'm changing the correct file, if you mean the css file. Hmm...when I load the css file in the browser the changes aren't showing...

Comment: This is the link to the css when I view source and that is the file I am changing... <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

Comment: @Sarah I can't say what could be the problem.. but I am guessing that the problem might be that the css is being overriding somehow.. maybe due to other css file or high specificity or use of `!important`. Can you please inspect the elements to make sure the overiding is not a problem here? (_I can't think of other problems, currently_)

Comment: Thank you! I worked it out - the host had a caching thing enabled so I manually flushed it on the server and it's working now Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use display:table-cell for this:

http://jsfiddle.net/6fjr8uc6/

```
ul#PrimaryNav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    clear: left;
    width:100%;
    display: table;
}    
ul#PrimaryNav li {
    display: table-cell;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: transparent url('../img/primarynavbg.jpg') bottom left repeat-x;
}
    ul#PrimaryNav li a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-right: solid 1px #f1f1f1;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #dcdcdc;
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I just tried this but nothing is changing. Do I have to do something to force the .css changes to take effect? I am refreshing the browser too so it's not a browser caching issue.